# grails security sorry we were not able to find a user with that username and password

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I know this has been asked by many and I have gone through all stackOverflow threads related to `spring-security` issues but still i am getting  `we were not able to find a user with that username and password` .

Below is my config values ...

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'OU=User Accounts,DC=tgs800,DC=org'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.domain = 'tgs800.org'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'displayName'] 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ='DC=tgs800,DC=org'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldaps://myldap.tgs800.org:636/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'myDN'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'mypassword'
```

I have added the LDAP root certificate in my `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file using `keytool`

I am just trying to use simple login authentication using LDAP. Is there anyway to check whether i am able to connect to our LDAP server or not and where can I check ldap related logs to debug more about my issue.

Using `in-memory database` without LDAP server i am able to make my application secure but want to use LDAP authentication where I no need to create any USers or Roles. Please advise me on this. Thanks a lot

## EDITED

[Here is the link for my log](https://gist.github.com/deepakrohan1/2df2a15e3d5118cb178b56403be6ebf7)

Comment: Did you check logs on LDAP site, not on Grails site? Can you log to your LDAP account with any other method (different software/command line)? Which implementation of LDAP are you using?

Comment: You can verify you connection settings using some other software like LDAPBrowser - http://www.ldapbrowser.com/info_softerra-ldap-browser.htm After you have correct values, you should be able to setup it in Grails config

Comment: sorry for the delay - i have been into other issues these days. Initially I was not able to connect to the ldap server because of wrong certs now I have checked my connection to ldaps server with SSLPOKE class and i am able to connect to the server as i have exported correct cert in my java cacerts but still getting the same issue. I have enabled debug mode for spring security and added the log details above. Please help me on this issue. Thanks a ton